# Add View Dialog MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I am busy changing the default T4 Templates that gets generated when I click on the "Add View" dialog from my Controller. I know how to change the templates. But the following i can not wrap my head around.

I want to be able to generate the following when the user clicks on Add View.

1. A partial view that only contains the Form part of the view that is generated by default
2. A View that calls the partial view generated above.

Is it possible to generate 2 files like this using the T4 Templates ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I know nothing about writing T4 but you may take look at T4 templates which create POCO and DbContext for Entity Framework. It actually create separate file for each type of classes

Comment: I know they are creating a seperate file type for each class, but i want to split this further.

Answer (score 0):

Why?  Are you going to be routinely doing this exact same thing over and over again?  If so, then a T4 template may make sense.  If you're doing it once or twice, then just modify the files by hand.

Comment: This will be used by all my normal CRUD Poco's. Use Case : I have a titles POCO. For this object i want to generate a partial view and then a view that uses the partial view. The reason for this is, when i show the titles dropdown on any other page, i want to include a add button, where the partialView will then be shown as a modal. To allow the users to quicklu add lookup types. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @Captain0 - I'm not sure you understand what T4 is.  T4 generates your physical views at design time.  When you are building your application.  It does not do anything at run time.  What you are talking about sounds more like a Master page or layout page.

Comment: I understand what a T4 is. You generate views with the T4 templates. At design time is exactly the time i want to generate the View, and the Partial View, I just gave the above as an example as to why i want to generate 2 views.